# event.target not recognized angular2

Tags: angular

I have a function

```
transferDataSuccess(event, cat,label ,e ){
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement || e.currentTarget;
    this.handler.emit( {e:event, cat:cat , labelCS:event.dragData.labelCS} );    
    this.unhighlightElement( event , e );
   
}
```

it is binded to element via

```
(onDropSuccess)="transferDataSuccess($event, node.id , node.label , $event)"
```

however it always results in error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

It cannot access event.target, does Angular2 have `event.target` or similar method? If no what is wrong with my piece of code? Why can't it find `event.target`?

// unhighlight function

```
  unhighlightElement( e , x ){
    e=e||window.event;
    var el =   x || e.target;
    //alert(el.nodeName)
    while( el.nodeName != 'DIV'){
        el = el.parentNode;
    }

    el.style.border="";

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();     
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be:

```
(onDropSuccess)="transferDataSuccess($event, node.id, node.label)"
```

and your function will look like:

```
transferDataSuccess(event, cat, label){
  this.handler.emit({ e:event, cat:cat, labelCS: event.dragData.labelCS });    
  this.unhighlightElement(event.mouseEvent);
}

unhighlightElement(e){
  var el = e.target;
  //alert(el.nodeName)
  while( el.nodeName != 'DIV'){
    el = el.parentNode;
  }

  el.style.border="";

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();     
}
```

See this line:
https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd/blob/09296dc1c0a5d7b04ae742d60f49c57398b4e375/src/dnd.droppable.ts#L82

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1zFXaINhSHEgHNtmE2NE?p=preview)

Comment: Can you provide the plunker that reproduces your problem?

Comment: it would require a lot of structure from code which is quite big. inside unhighlightElement i call store  var el =  e  || event.target which is undefined by mozilla

Comment: Can you share `unhighlightElement` method?

Comment: `this.unhighlightElement( event , e );` Here the second argument is mouseEvent. Try `var el = x.target;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118824/discussion-between-yurzui-and-j-dd).